# Writing fragment shaders: cannot make sense of how the uniforms are defined

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, phaser-framework, pixi.js

I'm trying to make custom filters with Phaser, but I don't get how the uniforms, and `vTextureCoord` in particular are specified. [Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5srLgp3/7/) (EDIT: Ignore the image, the minimal case lays in the square gradient):

- Why isn't the top-right corner white? I've set both the filter resolution and the sprite size to 256, yet `vTextureCoord` only goes from [0,0] to [.5,.5] (or so it seems)
- Try dragging the sprite: it seems to be blocked by a wall at the top and left borders. It's only shader-related though, as the game object itself is correctly dragged. How come?

I pulled my hair on this one during the last Ludum Dare, trying to figure out the pixel position within the sprite (i.e. [0,0] on the bottom left corner and [sprite.w, sprite.h] on the top right one)... But I couldn't find any reliable way to compute that whatever the sprite position and size are.

Thanks for your help!

---

**EDIT**: As *emackey* pointed out, it seems like either Phaser or Pixi (not sure at which level it's handled?) uses an intermediate texture. Because of this the `uSampler` I get is not the original texture, but a modified one, that is, for example, shifted/cropped if the sprite is beyond the top-left corner of the screen. The `uSampler` and `vTextureCoord` work well together, so as long as I'm making simple things like color tweaks all seems well, but for toying with texture coordinates it's simply not reliable.

Can a Phaser/Pixi guru explain why it works that way, and what I'm supposed to do to get clear coordinates and work with my actual source texture? [I managed to hack a shader](http://jsfiddle.net/q5srLgp3/18/) by "fixing `vTextureCoord`" and plugging my texture in `iChannel0`, but this feels a bit hacky.

Thanks.

Comment: About the second point: It seems that the dragging is going to be restricted whenever a filter is applied to the sprite. I tried with multiple filters and searched through the docs but couldn't find anything according to it.
Maybe it would be the best way to actually ask anyone at their dev team what this is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Phaser, but we can shed a little light on what that fragment shader is really doing.  Load your jsFiddle and replace the GLSL main body with this:

```
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vTextureCoord.x * 2., vTextureCoord.y * 2., 1., 1.);
    gl_FragColor *= texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord) * 0.6 + 0.4;
}
```

The above filter shader is a combination of the original texture (with some gray added) and your colors, so you can see both the texture and the UVs at the same time.

You're correct that `vTextureCoord` only goes to `0.5`, hence the `* 2.` above, but that's not the whole story:  Try dragging your sprite off the top-left.  The texture slides but the texture coordinates don't move!

How is that even possible?  My guess is that the original sprite texture is being rendered to an intermediate texture, using some of the sprite's location info for the transform.  By the time your custom filter runs, your filter GLSL code is running on what's now the transformed intermediate texture, and the texture coordinates no longer have a known relation to the original sprite texture.

If you run the [Chrome Canvas Inspector](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/inspection/) you can see that indeed there are multiple passes, including a render-to-texture pass.  You can also see that the filter pass is using coordinates that appear to be the ratio of the filter area size to the game area size, which in this case is `0.5` on both dimensions.

I don't know Phaser well enough to know if there's a quick fix for any of this.  Maybe you can add some uniforms to the filter that would give the shader the extra transform it needs, if you can figure out where that comes from exactly.  Or perhaps there's a way to attach a shader directly on the sprite itself (there's a null field of the same name) so you could possibly run your GLSL code there instead of in the filter.  I hope this answer has at least explained the "why" of your two questions above.

Comment: BTW, I mentioned the [Chrome Canvas Inspector](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/inspection/) for snooping on WebGL calls, and there are more tools like this, for example the [Firefox Canvas Debugger](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/03/introducing-the-canvas-debugger-in-firefox-developer-tools/).  Someone I know wrote a good article on [WebGL Debugging and Profiling Tools](http://www.realtimerendering.com/blog/webgl-debugging-and-profiling-tools/).

Comment: Thanks for the explaination & the reasoning behind it. You're right, what lost me is this intermediate texture that shifts/crops/resizes the original one. Not sure why things are made that way (maybe because of performance concerns?), at least I now have the right questions to ask to the Phaser/PixiJS people. With some fiddling I managed to make things work by keeping these `vTextureCoord` bounds in mind and by adding the texture I want as a custom uniform, since the default texture is not reliable. Result at: http://jsfiddle.net/q5srLgp3/18/

Comment: I'm keeping the question open a bit longer, to see if I can get some Phaser/Pixi-specific info, hopefully to understand why things are made that way.